# Python SpaCy Create nlp Document - Argument 'string' has incorrect type

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm relatively new to Python NLP and I am trying to process a CSV file with SpaCy. I'm able to load the file just fine using Pandas, but when I attempt to process it with SpaCy's nlp function, the compiler errors out approximately 5% of the way through the file's contents.

Code block follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./reviews.washington.dc.csv')

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

for parsed_doc in nlp.pipe(iter(df['comments']), batch_size=1, n_threads=4):
    print (parsed_doc.text)
```

I've also tried:

```
df['parsed'] = df['comments'].apply(nlp)
```

with the same result.

The traceback I'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/john/Downloads/spacy_load.py", line 11, in <module>
        for parsed_doc in nlp.pipe(iter(df['comments']), batch_size=1,
        n_threads=4):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py",
        line 352, in pipe for doc in stream:
    File "spacy/syntax/parser.pyx", line 239, in pipe
        (spacy/syntax/parser.cpp:8912)
    File "spacy/matcher.pyx", line 465, in pipe (spacy/matcher.cpp:9904)
    File "spacy/syntax/parser.pyx", line 239, in pipe (spacy/syntax/parser.cpp:8912)
    File "spacy/tagger.pyx", line 231, in pipe (spacy/tagger.cpp:6548)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 345,
        in <genexpr> stream = (self.make_doc(text) for text in texts)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 293,
        in <lambda> self.make_doc = lambda text: self.tokenizer(text)
    TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got float)
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening, as well as how I might work around it? I've tried various workarounds from the site to no avail. Try/except blocks have had no effect, either.

Comment: I'd start by inspecting `df.comments`. If your CSV is badly formatted you could get floats from adjacent columns sneaking into the `comments` column, which would cause the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks - I'm exploring that now and have added an explicit type conversion to the DataFrame.

Comment: Can you use the 'except' part of try/except to print out the doc which is causing the problem? Is it getting half way through the loop or crashing on the first item..

Answer (score 1):

I've just been experiencing a very similar error to the one you received.

```
>>> c.add_texts(df.DetailedDescription.astype('object'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site
-packages\textacy\corpus.py", line 297, in add_texts
    for i, spacy_doc in enumerate(spacy_docs):
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site
-packages\spacy\language.py", line 554, in pipe
    for doc in docs:
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 369, in pipe
  File "cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx", line 1046, in cytoolz.itertoolz.partition_all.__
next__ (cytoolz/itertoolz.c:14538)
    for item in self.iterseq:
  File "nn_parser.pyx", line 369, in pipe
  File "cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx", line 1046, in cytoolz.itertoolz.partition_all.__
next__ (cytoolz/itertoolz.c:14538)
    for item in self.iterseq:
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 395, in pipe
  File "cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx", line 1046, in cytoolz.itertoolz.partition_all.__
next__ (cytoolz/itertoolz.c:14538)
    for item in self.iterseq:
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site
-packages\spacy\language.py", line 534, in <genexpr>
    docs = (self.make_doc(text) for text in texts)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site
-packages\spacy\language.py", line 357, in make_doc
    return self.tokenizer(text)
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got float)
```

Finally, I happened across a solution, which was to use the Pandas data frame to cast values to Unicode before retrieving the values as a native array and feeding that into the `add_texts` method of the Textacy `Corpus` object.

```
c = textacy.corpus.Corpus(lang='en_core_web_lg')
c.add_texts(df.DetailedDescription.astype('unicode').values)
df.DetailedDescription.astype('unicode').values
```

Doing this allowed me to add all texts to my corpus, despite trying to forcefully load a Unicode compliant file before hand (snippet included below in case that helps others).

```
with codecs.open('Base Data\Base Data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as base_data:
  df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(re.sub(r'(?!\n)[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]', '', base_data.read())), dtype={"DetailedDescription":object, "OtherDescription":object}, na_values=[''])
```